# Is there a possibility that $|Corr(X,Y)|=1$ and there's no linear relationship between them?

Tags: probability

Let us have $|Corr(X,Y)|=1$.

When is it possible for the variables $X,Y$ not be linearly related?

I would say that they must have infinite moments... But I'm not seeing if that's enough to get the result I want.

Answer (score 1):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $X$ is a constant multiple of $Y$ in this case.

Comment: We can use Cauchy-Schwarz only if we have $E(XY)$ finite.

Comment: We can have $\operatorname{Corr}(XY)$ only if $E(XY)$, $E(X^2)$, and $E(Y^2)$ are all finite.